# Why attacker do not care about masking the IP of the infected device of botnet?

Tags: botnet

I get a sentence:

> If an attack is created using a botnet the likelihood of tracking the attack back to its source is low. For an added level of obfuscation, an attacker may have each distributed device also spoof the IP addresses from which it sends packets. If the attacker is using a botnet such as the Mirai botnet, they generally won’t care about masking the IP of the infected device.

Why attacker do not care about masking the IP of the infected device of botnet?

Comment: where is the quote from? Always cite your sources.

Answer (score 3):

Infected devices are not owned by the attacker. So, it doesn't matter to the attacker if the bots are found.

Mirai was so successful that if a device was found, the attacker could simply get another.

Other botnets might be carefully controlled and tended by the attacker. They might be difficult or costly to maintain or to add new bots. In these cases, the attacker would want to protect it as much as feasible.